# Oracle: how to substract a date from table column from a fixed date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table containing a column in date format named "date_started". I want to substract all the dates from this column from a fixed date, for example 31.03.2022, resulting in a new column "absolut days" showing difference between two dates in days.

I tried with the following statement:

*SELECT ('31.03.2022'- date_started) AS absolut days
FROM ....*

Unfortunately i am not able to find a workaround for the resulting Error message:

*ORA-00932: Inkonsistente Datentypen: CHAR erwartet, DATE erhalten
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"*

I am beginner in SQL, exspecially in Oracle and looking forward for some help, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'31.03.2022'` may look like a date but it is not a `DATE` data type; it is a string literal.

If you want a `DATE` data type then you can use a date literal:

```sql
SELECT DATE '2022-03-31' - date_started AS absolut_days
FROM   your_table;
```

Or convert your string to a date:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE('31.03.2022', 'DD.MM.YYYY') - date_started AS absolut_days
FROM   your_table;
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table (date_started) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ABSOLUT_DAYS |
| --- |
| 89 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b57b50aaadd471cc132eb24caed671a3)*